# Are we by default at war with all of the Disbelieving Peoples?

Tags: jihad, war

suppose theres no formally agreed pact between the Ummah and any Disbelieving nations, and the disbelieving Nations have not attacked us and expressed a desire for Peace.

Are we still at war (islamically speaking) until
A formal pact is agreed upon?

Comment: If you mean: Is there an assumption of peace? Then, the answer is no. Peace with non-Muslims is something that needs to be positively confirmed whether that is through treaties, international agreements, or something else.

Comment: That of course is not the same as saying we are required to be at war with them. Lack of binding peace is not the same as the positive existence of war

Comment: @TheZ yeah thats what i meant.  ... so We dont have to wage war against Kuffar ? But didnt allah command us to wage war until all religion is for allah ? (8.39)

Comment: The Prophet was not waging war mindlessly on the neighboring nations, the Prophet sent messages to the rulers of these states inviting them to Islam, then worked accordingly based on their choices to believe his message or not, Persia and Byzantine are examples.

Answer (score -1):

The Holy Quran, Sūrat l-māidah 5:16

> God guides with it whoever follows His approval to the ways of peace,
> and He brings them out of darkness into light, by His permission, and
> He guides them in a straight path.

The Holy Quran, Sūrat l-fur'qān 25:47-56

> And it is He who made the night a covering for you, and sleep for
> rest; and He made the day a revival. And it is He who sends the winds,
> bringing advance news of His mercy; and We send down from the sky pure
> water. To revive dead lands thereby, and to provide drink for the
> multitude of animals and humans We created. We have circulated it
> among them, that they may reflect, but most people persist in
> thanklessness. Had We willed, We could have sent to every town a
> warner. So do not obey the disbelievers, but *jihad* them with it, a
> mighty *jihad*. And it is He who merged the two seas; this one fresh
> and sweet, and that one salty and bitter; and He placed between them a
> barrier, and an impassable boundary. And it is He who, from fluid,
> created the human being. Then He made relationships through marriage
> and mating. Your Lord is Omnipotent. And yet, instead of God, they
> serve what neither profits them nor harms them. The disbeliever has
> always turned his back on his Lord. We sent you only as a herald of
> good news and a warner.

How does this part of the Quran begin? It is a picture of harmony, a harmony created by Him.
In contrast to old polytheist myths (e.g. Sumeric/Accadic and Greek), where the beginning of the world is described by a war between different deities, we got to know that God prepared the world in harmony. The original state of the world is harmony, not war.

In the middle of the text, we find the verse "So do not obey the disbelievers, but *jihad* them with it in a mighty *jihad*." where I left the word *jihad* untranslated. "with it" refers to the Message of God, in particular the Quran. We shall *jihad* with the Word of God.

God sent His messenger (p.b.u.h) because they do not recognise His magnificent work, only as a herald of good news and a warner.

As the initial state of the world is peace, the initial state for humans living side by side is peace, not war. A peace treaty is not required when there has been no war. What is commanded is *jihad* with the Word of God. The Word of God is not the sword, and *jihad* by the Word is underlined by an exemplary goodness of the one who gives the message. And it will not convince anybody if it is said by someone who from the beginning on is hostile. Who should then accept the message of Allah, the Most Merciful, the Most Compassionate? Who would then read the Quran until the 41st Sura, saying:

The Holy Quran, Sūrat fuṣṣilat 41:30-34

> Surely, those who say: “Our Lord is God,” and then go straight, the
> angels will descend upon them: “Do not fear, and do not grieve, but
> rejoice in the news of the Garden which you were promised. We are your
> allies in this life and in the Hereafter, wherein you will have
> whatever your souls desire, and you will have therein whatever you
> call for. As Hospitality from an All-Forgiving, Merciful One.” And who
> is better in speech than someone who calls to God, and acts with
> integrity, and says, “I am of those who submit”? Good and evil are not
> equal. Repel evil with good, and the person who was your enemy becomes
> like an intimate friend.